# How to design a fast way to `unarchive` file using python?

Tags: design, architecture, python, multithreading, service-workers

Assuming the following scenario:

A python application that receives file and process that file trying to understand what the file format( any type of data/compressions/archives/packages/mounts/etc ), then it open(cuts) the file and sees which files are inside that file and tries to execute the same logic as before.
All relevant information that the script can get from files must be stored in the database in order to present it in the UI( in the form of a tree ).

- Parent file should be available to share info with his child files
- After all files are extracted and data collected there are some post process scripts( example: to connect js function names in html file with js file )

how it woks now:
one worker come up with x threads that listening to python queue, and when first file_path come into queue it start work and fill that queue with child files. All related information are saved into python list and then it send batches into db(arangodb).

what problems with that solution:

- Hard to debug with multithreading, specially if thread is stuck. renewing the thread
- No easy way to catch errors, only in logs

questions:

- do a task queue/job queue like Celery/rq/dramatiq will fit here? If yes, which one on your opinion?
- publisher-subscriber pattern will fit here or it's overcomplicating?

Maybe you know some articles/companies/products that seems familiar?

Comment: Why are you concerned with multithreading and concurrency for this problem? The problem seems quite simple to me, but it does seem that you are severely overcomplicating it by all the technologies you want to use.

Comment: You're not actually speeding up any processing by going for multithreading, you're just making your code run _concurrently_, not in parallel. If you have a connection w/ the frontend, perhaps updating the percentage of files processed in soft-realtime or if you have multiple clients and you care about responsiveness, then you might want concurrency. No reason for bringing in pub/sub whatsoever here.

Comment: @VincentSavard for example you received a file.zip that contains 10 other zip files, it will speed up a process if 10 threads will read those files. Work with files is I/O bound and threads are good at such work, tested :) sure if you can advise some other options to speed up process, I'm glad to hear

Comment: Just to clarify, at what stage of the development are you? Do you have a complete, working solution and you measured that the bottleneck is caused by I/O? Is the bottleneck actually an issue in practice? My understanding of the question (which may be entirely wrong, I concede) is that you're currently not at the point where you have a working solution, and are already trying to optimize it. Beware of premature optimization!

Comment: Thread is good at pararelizing I/O bound work, yes, but you can't speed up file reads with multiple threads, as file reads are capped by the I/O bus speed and drive speed. You can only speed up the CPU-heavy part of a workload using multiple threads (i.e. the decompression, not the file read). Given the right workload and algorithm, a single thread running in a single CPU core can easily saturate the I/O queue.

Comment: @LieRyan only for clarification, 1 file - 1 thread, not a couple of threads for reading 1 file

Comment: @EdvardKrol: That makes no difference. If your random disk read speed is 500MB/s with one thread, with ten threads reading ten files it'll still be 500MB/s just divided ten ways. Unless your disk read speed well exceeds your decompression speed, using multiple threads won't make things any faster in this case. Unless you used the highest compression levels with compression algorithms like lzma or bz2 which has slow decompression speed and you are running on really speedy SSD, usually I/O would be slower than decompression.

Comment: @VincentSavard the project has a working solution and in development & implementation stage. I tested 26 MB file with ~3000 files in, and multithreading solution took =~90 seconds to run, and with 1 thread =~ 135s. The question is: will distributed task processing library like Celery/rq/etc serve this faster?

Comment: @LieRyan yup, in some cases, we use lzma and bz2. I did a couple of tests and put a results above in comments, so yes, multithreading speed up a process here( maybe cause sometimes we run cmd commands to open/extract data from file ). Lets say that a project should work with any type of files/compressions/archives/packages/mounts that exists. I will update the post, thanks for pointing